# How to allow only "git tag" from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows-server-2016

We need to only allow tags to be created from Jenkins pipelines, which means we need to disallow specific commands such as "git commit".

Jenkins agents' OS is Windows Server 2016. It could also be something done at Jenkins master level.

Any recommendations?

Thank you

Comment: What is the remote host repository system?

Comment: Gitea (self hosted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest level of authorization in Jenkins is project-based security via the [Matrix Authorization Strategy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/).

The only idea that comes into my mind atm:

1. Remove Git's binary folder from `PATH`.
2. Create a wrapper `git.cmd` or `git.ps1` that only accepts arguments from a whitelist of Git commands.
3. a) Add the wrapper's folder to your `PATH`.
   b) Refer to the wrapper in Jenkins' ***Global Tool Configuration*** → ***Git***.

Comment: I confirm that the proposed solution works wonders. Thank you Gerold Broser